# RGBDSLAM GUI not getting data from kinect

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey....

I have been trying to run RGBDSLAM with kinect on my PC. I have downloaded openNI drivers as suggested. And Kinect is giving data if i run only openNI launch files.

But when i try to run rgbdslam+kinect.launch, it shows the gui but its not getting data from kinect.
Its showing 'Waiting for monochrome image'.....
further more i am not using ubuntu on VNware....
please help me out....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31690/rgbdslam-gui-not-getting-data-from-kinect/) by [Naman Goyal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2131/naman-goyal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is, that you use openni_launch instead of openni_camera and need to adapt the topics in the launch file:

```
<param name="config/topic_image_mono"              value="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
<param name="config/topic_image_depth"             value="/camera/depth_registered/image"/>
<param name="config/topic_points"                  value="/camera/depth_registered/points"/>
```

Also you need to enable registration of depth and color, e.g. via dynamic_reconfigure. [See this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/2905/activating-openni-depth-registration-by-default) for how to enable registration by default.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0